# Toggle Divs working on web but not in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, crm

I'm working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 and am trying to create a data toggle block, which would toggle values according to which category is selected. The list has 7 div's and should only show the div selected (i.e. div 3), not showing all of the others. The html is working like a charm in a browser but not in CRM, meaning none of the categories are toggling when js, css, and html are added to CRM 2013 with a webresource. I am not a developer but need to figure out how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated!! 
This is the entire html webresource entered into CRM
**This was created in jsfiddle but I'm having massive issues.** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DeanaJ/17hauc0q/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=17hauc0q#&togetherjs=wM14QSuGb7)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        div:not(#div0) {
    display: none;
}
    </style>
    <script src="js_files/snippet-javascript-console.js"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="js_files/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div1">div1</a><br>
    <div id="div1">div1 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2">div2</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div2">div2 information?</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3">div3</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div3">div3 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div4">div4</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div4">div4</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div5">div5</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div5">div5 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div6">div6</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div6">div6 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div7">div7</a><br>
    <div id="div7">div7 information</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  $("div").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body></html>
```

This is the snippet from within stackoverflow.

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  $("div").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```

```css
div:not(#div0) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div1">div1</a><br>
    <div id="div1">div1 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2">div2</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div2">div2 information?</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3">div3</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div3">div3 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div4">div4</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div4">div4</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div5">div5</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div5">div5 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div6">div6</a>
    <br>
    <div id="div6">div6 information</div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#div7">div7</a><br>
    <div id="div7">div7 information</div>
```

***Thank you so much!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jQuery `.toggle()`  / `.show()` / `.hide()` methods are not working in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, you can toggle the divs with CSS alone.

**Working Example:**

```css
a {
display: block;
line-height: 36px;
cursor: pointer;
}

a + div {
display: none;
margin: -48px 0 12px;
padding-top: 48px;
}

div:target {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#div1">div1</a>
<div id="div1">div1 information</div>

<a href="#div2">div2</a>
<div id="div2">div2 information</div>

<a href="#div3">div3</a>
<div id="div3">div3 information</div>

<a href="#div4">div4</a>
<div id="div4">div4 information</div>

<a href="#div5">div5</a>
<div id="div5">div5 information</div>

<a href="#div6">div6</a>
<div id="div6">div6 information</div>

<a href="#div7">div7</a>
<div id="div7">div7 information</div>
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius!!! It finally worked! Thank you so very much. I wish I could vote on your excellent and very quick response and fix for my dilemma, but I'm still a newbie unfortunately. Just wondering, how did you know that you didn't have to use jquery?

Comment: One of the issues jQuery sought to tackle when John Resig first released it in January 2006 was to enable commonplace effects and animations to work cross-browser without hacks and fixes. But we have come a long, long way in 11 years... the idea that all browsers should all promote universally interoperable standards (rather than proprietary innovations) prevailed, javascript has evolved and evolved (based on no small amount of inspiration from jQuery) and... CSS has substantially evolved too. Effects & animations commonly delivered via jQuery in 2007 are now routinely written in CSS.

Comment: Here's a site you may find useful as you continue to learn: http://www.youmightnotneedjquery.com/ The key idea behind the site is that plain javascript and Internet Explorer have evolved so much that .js code which jQuery massively simplified (when it was first introduced) may be just as simple to write in plain javascript in 2017.

Comment: And having mentioned that site, I can't not mention http://youmightnotneedjs.com/ which, inspired by the site above, seeks to demonstrate that many animations and effects which used to be delivered via scripting can now be handled better and more smoothly via the (greatly evolved) CSS we have available today.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you Rounin for providing these phenomenal resources! I love to learn, thus these links will definitely assist in getting much better at this. Thank you